# Synchronising one Yahoo! email account from another Yahoo! account?

Tags: yahoo-mail, synchronization, yahoo-account

I had connected a Yahoo! email (`account 1`) under another Yahoo! email (`account 2`). I accessed `account 1` almost exclusively through this connection through `account 2`.

Apparently, during the data breaches, Yahoo! unauthorized this connection for my security. However, I was not made aware immediately. As a result, I moved some ~4,000 old emails in `account 1` (via the connected folder in `account 2`) while it was not *actually* synchronised. So the un-synced folder for `account1` in `account 2` reflects the moves/updates, but the actual `account 1` email does not.

**My Question:** Is there a way to re-sync the emails in a way that captures/saves all of the moves I made in the un-synced/disconnected `account1` folder in `account2` to copy to the "real" account?

**Put differently:** can I replace the locations of messages in a Yahoo! account with the location of those emails in a no-longer synced folder of that account?

Answer (score 1):

What might be best if all your data is still on your old mailbox folder, backup what you have then delete it and do a full re-sync and check you have not got anything missing.

Always best to backup and resync in full in situations like this.